# writing and reading input to xml

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing

I am new to Android development and have been struggling with a problem.  I have been trying to learn how to save user inputs to file.  I have asked a similar answer and ended up figuring out a solution although it didn't work out the way I want.  I have been searching high and low about how to write files to xml.  I would to have a user be able to save, add, retreive, and be able to remove items from an XML file.  I think the problem I am having as far as learning this is I'm not sure what the processes are call to properly look for a solution.  This isn't for school work, I'm not looking for anyone to write up some code for me.  What I am hoping for is proper terminology, maybe a link to some helpful information and such.  I believe this process is called parsing, and you can add to XML through appending, not sure about much after this.  Thank you in advance to anyone who can offer assistance.

Comment: android has a library called XmlPullParser android has basic documentation here http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html  and this link has a tutorial on using the XmlPullParser they parse a atom feed in this particular example i believe http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html

Answer (score 1):

To have the XML always available for the app you should put it in the "assets" folder. You should copy-paste the xml file to modify it, to ensure the file won't be corrupted afterwards.

First you have to copy the xml to the sdcard (preferably to a folder with your app name as folder name), you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447477/android-how-to-copy-files-from-assets-folder-to-sdcard) to learn how to copy a file. After you have done that you can use the [JDOM Parser](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-modify-xml-file-in-java-jdom/) to modify that xml file.

Put the xml after the modification back in the assets folder.